# TypeError: gassens() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter, tk-toolkit

this code get the gas sensor from esp8266 (using  "RequestHandler_httpd(BaseHTTPRequestHandler)")
I want it to show on the key when it receives the gas sensor(on "class HelloWorld -> def gassens")
but get this error :
File "panel2.py", line 124, in do_GET
HelloWorld.gassens()
TypeError: gassens() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

i'm beginner in python please help
tnx

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import requests
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

gas = 0
hum = ''
g = 0
TheRequest = None
roomp=''
lump = 0
class HelloWorld:
    global lump
    global gas
    def __init__(self, master):
      frame = Frame(master)
      frame.pack()

      frame.columnconfigure(     0, pad    = 2)
      frame.columnconfigure(     1, pad    = 2)
      frame.rowconfigure(        0, pad    = 2)
      frame.rowconfigure(        1, pad    = 2)
      frame.rowconfigure(        2, pad    = 2)


      self.button = Button(
            frame, text="Hello", command=self.button_pressed
            )
      #self.button.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5)
      self.button.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=10, sticky=W+E+N+S)

      self.label = Label(frame, text="this is label")
      #self.label.pack()
      self.label.grid(row=0, column=1)

       buttonStyle = Style()
      buttonStyle.configure(  "Normal.TButton",
                            background        = "#91C497",
                            borderwidth       = 1,
                            activeforeground  = "#30903C",
                            compound          = "BOTTOM")
      buttonStyle.configure(  "Selected.TButton",
                            background        = "#107B1D",
                            borderwidth       = 1,
                            activeforeground  = "#30903C",
                            compound          = "BOTTOM")

      self.fanImage = PhotoImage(file="icons/ac.png")
      self.addImage = PhotoImage(file="icons/add.png")
      self.extractor_button = Button(   frame,
                                      text      = "Extractor",
                                      command   = self.toggleFan,
                                      image     = self.fanImage,
                                      style     = "Normal.TButton")
      #self.extractor_button.pack()
      self.extractor_button.grid(row=1, column=1)

      self.label2 = Label(frame, text="gas-sensor is here")
      self.label2.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan  = 2)


    def button_pressed(self):
      TheRequest = requests.get('http://192.168.43.91/off')


     def toggleFan(self):
      global lump
      if lump == 0 :
        TheRequest = requests.get('http://192.168.43.91/on')
        self.extractor_button.config(image=self.fanImage,style="Selected.TButton")
        lump = 1
      else :
        TheRequest = requests.get('http://192.168.43.91/off')
        self.extractor_button.config(image=self.fanImage,style="Normal.TButton")
        lump = 0

#PROBLEM HERE    
    def gassens(self):
      global gas  
      self.label2.config(text=gas)
    

class RequestHandler_httpd(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  def do_GET(self):
    global gas
    global hum
    global g
    print('you got this massage')
    print("request ::",self.requestline)

    req = self.requestline
    tstgas = req.find ("gas")
    tsthum = req.find ("hum")
    if tstgas == 5 :
        gas = str()
        gas = req.replace("GET /gas", "")
        gas = gas.replace(" HTTP/1.1", "")
        print("gaz :"+gas)
        gas = int(gas)
#PROBLEM HERE
        HelloWorld.gassens()
    
    messagetosend = bytes('this is from pi',"utf")
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
    self.send_header('Content-Length', len(messagetosend))
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write(messagetosend)
    return
def server_rp():
  global gas
  global g
  try:

      server_address_httpd = ('192.168.43.211',8080)
      httpd = HTTPServer(server_address_httpd, RequestHandler_httpd)
      print('server is started!')
      httpd.serve_forever()
  except:
      print("khata dar server")

def main():
  root = Tk()
  root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
  ex = HelloWorld(root)
  root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  p1 = Process(target=main)
  p1.start()
  p2 = Process(target=server_rp)
  p2.start()
  p1.join()
  p2.join()
```

Comment: In general, don't use the 'global' modifier, this is bad programming practice.

Comment: I think the problem is that you need to call ex.gassens() inside your request handler class rather than helloworld.gassens().

Comment: ex.gassens() is'nt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access tkinter widgets in another process directly.  So use `threading.Thread` instead of `multiprocessing.Process` on the HTTP server part and run the tkinter GUI in the main thread.

Below is suggested changes based on your code:

```
from threading import Thread
...
class HelloWorld:
    ...
    def gassens(self, gas):
        self.label2.config(text=gas)

class RequestHandler_httpd(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        # send back response
        messagetosend = b'this is from pi'
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
        self.send_header('Content-Length', len(messagetosend))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(messagetosend)

        req = self.requestline
        tstgas = req.find('gas')
        if tstgas == 5:
            # requestline: GET /gasXXX HTTP/1.1
            gas = req.split()[1][4:]
            print('gaz:', gas)
            ex.gassens(gas)
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run tkinter GUI in main thread
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('250x150+300+300')
    ex = HelloWorld(root)
    # using thread instead of process
    Thread(target=server_rp, daemon=True).start()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way you call a method in Python. If it was Java and gassens was static, you could do this. However, there's no concept of static variables in Python.

```
HelloWorld.gassens()
```

Instead, you want to create an *instance* of the class to use the function gassens. For example:

```
gas = HelloWorld(masterParam)
gas.gassens()
```

Comment: i get this error:> File "panel2.py", line 124, in do_GET
    gas=HelloWorld(masterParam)
NameError: name 'masterParam' is not defined

Comment: @AliKheyrandish The variable is just an example. You need to provide the variable master for your initializer.